# How can I split sub-strings to new rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe which contains data that is entered without whitespace between words, i.e VolvoSaabVauxhall = Volvo Saab Vauxhall. I want to separate each word and insert new rows for each word that contain same data as row they originated from -

```
type                year colour
Mazda               1990 Cyan
VolvoSaabVauxhall   2000 Red
Lada                1980 Black
```

becomes

```
type          year  colour
Mazda         1990  Cyan
Volvo         2000  Red
Saab          2000  Red
Vauxhall      2000  Red
Lada          1980  Black
```

what is the best way to achieve this without using iteration?

Comment: so Capital letter is your turning point right

Comment: Yes, it's always a Capital letter preceded by a lower case letter

Answer (score 2):

you say

> it's always a Capital letter preceded by a lower case letter

so a regex for it is

```
[A-Z][^A-Z]*
```

capital letter ([A-Z]), followed by zero or more (*) not-capital letters (with ^).

- So we can `findall` such matches
- Assign the `type` column to be the list of those findings
- explode the type column

So in code:

```py
df.type = df.type.str.findall(r"[A-Z][^A-Z]*")
df      = df.explode("type", ignore_index=True)
```

(if you want to be cool to write it in one line, lookup `assign`)

sample run:

```py
In [436]: df
Out[436]:
                type  year colour
0              Mazda  1990   Cyan
1  VolvoSaabVauxhall  2000    Red
2               Lada  1980  Black

In [437]: df.type.str.findall(r"[A-Z][^A-Z]*")
Out[437]:
0                    [Mazda]
1    [Volvo, Saab, Vauxhall]
2                     [Lada]
Name: type, dtype: object

In [438]: df.type = df.type.str.findall(r"[A-Z][^A-Z]*")

In [439]: df
Out[439]:
                      type  year colour
0                  [Mazda]  1990   Cyan
1  [Volvo, Saab, Vauxhall]  2000    Red
2                   [Lada]  1980  Black

In [440]: df.explode("type", ignore_index=True)
Out[440]:
       type  year colour
0     Mazda  1990   Cyan
1     Volvo  2000    Red
2      Saab  2000    Red
3  Vauxhall  2000    Red
4      Lada  1980  Black
```

I passed `ignore_index=True` to `explode`; you can unpass and see what it does!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.str.extractall('([A-Z][^A-Z]+)')` to extract all the uppercase word and `join` it to reset dataframe

```py
out = ((df.pop('type').str.extractall('([A-Z][^A-Z]+)').droplevel(-1))
       .join(df).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={0: 'type'}))
```

```
print(out)

       type  year colour
0     Mazda  1990   Cyan
1     Volvo  2000    Red
2      Saab  2000    Red
3  Vauxhall  2000    Red
4      Lada  1980  Black
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on the idea of splitting multiple types into lists ([`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)) and exploding those lists afterwards:

```
(df.assign(type = df.type.str.split('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', regex = True))
  .explode('type'))
```

Output:

```
       type  year colour
0     Mazda  1990   Cyan
1     Volvo  2000    Red
1      Saab  2000    Red
1  Vauxhall  2000    Red
2      Lada  1980  Black
```